# Not an authentic device on iOS app using Google Cast 3.5

Tags: google-cast

I'm starting to migrate my GoogleCast integration from v2 to v3.5 on iOS when I run your code lab sample I always receive the current errors:

CastVideos-ios[436:35929] -[GCKDeviceAuthChannel didReceiveBinaryMessage:]  Device is revoked by CRL.
CastVideos-ios[436:35929] -[GCKCastDeviceConnector deviceAuthChannel:didFailToAuthenticateWithError:]  Not an authentic device, disconnecting.

Obviously the videos are not casting to my Chromecast 2.

I'm using the kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID to initialize the GCKCastContext﻿

Comment: In [v3](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/ios_migrate_sender), make sure that you have initialized the [`GCKCastContext`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_context) singleton using an appropriate [`GCKCastOptions`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_cast_options) to specify the receiver application ID and any other global options. This is typically done in the `AppDelegate -[application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method.

Comment: It's correctly initialized, and also is on my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: still not working

Answer (score -1):

We recommend that you take a look at the sample app on how to correctly integrate the Cast SDK with your app: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios

It is very important that you support the Cast lifecycle correctly.